# Java locks a newly created directory

Tags: java, windows, filesystems

I am copying recursively a directory, and tried with:

- `FileSystemUtils#copyRecursively` of Spring
- `FileUtils#copyDirectory` of Apache Commons
- A custom code

Sometimes I need to delete or move this directory and I cannot do that without restarting my application (I got a `java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException`).

I'm testing on Windows. Even with Windows Explorer, the directory cannot be deleted. I guess my issue is inherent to Windows but I didn't found much documentation about that.

Any idea or solution?

Comment: Adding some code to the question will make it easier to answer, and be more useful for people that have the same question in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException` could mean that directory is currently being accessed. The fact that restarting your application solves the problem makes me think that it's actually your application uses the directory.

You can check this theory using one of the ways specified [in this Super User topic](https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows). If you find that java process holds a lock on the directory then you'll need to double check your code to see why this happens.

Comment: Thank you, you put me in the good way. I was so sure my issue was because of the copy that I didn't check well my code. And thanks for the tip in the super topic ;)